# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name in /home/magento/web/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Message.php

Tags: magento2, php, linux

When I ran the command `php bin/magento s:s:d -f` while upgrading Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.4, I get the following error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name in /home/magento/web/magento2.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/public_html/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Message.php on line 394`

I picked up the command from a SO answer so I would prefer to have the commands from the Magento devdoc to do the same thing. Could you please help us?

Comment: i think laminas dependencies have been removed in latest version

Comment: What's the fix for this, then?

Comment: share your code, its eaiser with that for somebody to answer'

Comment: There isn't any code to share because this is the error message seen in the terminal upon running the command mentioned in the post. I got to know that this error is because of lower PHP version than PHP 8.0.